# Scraping a div inside two divs using beautiful soup doesn't return anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So basically i'm trying to scrape the value of a `div class = "stx-field-value"` inside a `div id = "Open"` which is inside the main `div class = "stx-tooltip"` but the code i've written doesn't give an ouput. It doesn't give any error either. What am i doing wrong?

The following [links to yahoo](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HDFCBANK.NS/chart?p=HDFCBANK.NS#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-)

The following links to image of the site i'm trying to scrape
[image]

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def ParsePrice():
    total_calls_a_day= 1
    while total_calls_a_day<3:
        total_calls_a_day+=1
        # time.sleep(60)
         
        
        company = 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HDFC.NS/chart?p=HDFC.NS'
        r=requests.get(company)
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

        for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'stx-tooltip'}):

            bar = foo.find('div', attrs={'id': 'Open'})
            for check in bar:
                close = check.find('div', attrs={'class': 'stx-field-value'}).text
            
                print(close)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ParsePrice()
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you see in the browser are loaded via JavaScript. You can use Yahoo API to load the data in Json format.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/HDFCBANK.NS?symbol=HDFCBANK.NS&period1=1569362400&period2=1594296314&interval=1d&includePrePost=true&events=div|split|earn&lang=en-IN&region=IN'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('{:>10} {:>10}'.format('Open', 'Close'))
for o, c in zip(data['chart']['result'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0]['open'],
                data['chart']['result'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0]['close']):
    print('{:>10.3f} {:>10.3f}'.format(float('nan') if o is None else o, float('nan') if c is None else c))
```

Prints:

```
      Open      Close
  1249.900   1239.700
  1239.800   1242.500
  1248.250   1244.200
  1228.800   1227.450
  1231.500   1248.800
  1239.950   1223.550
  1236.650   1189.700
  1201.200   1186.900
  1197.100   1228.150
  1221.800   1200.550
  1213.400   1198.800
  1209.000   1204.400
  1207.000   1223.050
  1231.650   1221.100
  1227.500   1220.000
  1225.450   1229.000
  1257.000   1239.300
  1246.850   1241.600
  1248.000   1236.100
  1240.000   1229.000
       nan        nan
  1238.000   1242.500
  1246.900   1248.350

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The answer by Andrej Kesely is much better

---

The website doesn't have an 'stx-tooltip' class defined in the html. It is most likely added via js. Beautiful Soup only parses HTML so it won't work. You can try selenium in headless mode for this.

Comment: How can we distinguish if a class is defined in the html vs a class that's added via js? I mean when we inspect the element of that page there is a div with a class "stx-tooltip"